# regex specific tags from text?

Tags: c#, regex, string-matching

i have the following text

```
<fieldset>
 <ul id="ContentPlaceHolder2_1g" class="profList column ui-sortable">
<legend class="group">المجموعه 1</legend>
<li id="ContentPlaceHolder2_8">محمود حسن ابراهيم عبد الصمد</li>
 /ul></fieldset>
  <fieldset>
 <ul id="ContentPlaceHolder2_2g" class="profList column ui-sortable">
 <legend class="group">المجموعه 2</legend>
 <li id="ContentPlaceHolder2_9">محمود فتحى ابراهيم عبد الصمد</li>
  <li id="ContentPlaceHolder2_10">احمد محسن احمد على</li>
   <li class="" style="" id="ContentPlaceHolder2_3">احمد درويش محمود عباس</li>
 </ul>
 </fieldset>

 <fieldset>
  <ul id="ContentPlaceHolder2_3g" class="profList column ui-sortable">
   <legend class="group">المجموعه 3</legend>
 <li id="ContentPlaceHolder2_11">محمد سيد محمد سيد</li>
  </ul>

 </fieldset>
```

i want to loop through it to get every   ul tag and il inside it inedd the all elemet in ul tag and every ul tag in array

Comment: Have a look at [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var list = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("ul")
    .Select(n => n.Descendants("li").Select(li => new {id=li.Id,text=li.InnerText }).ToList())
    .ToList();

foreach (var ul in list)
{
    foreach(var li in ul)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(li.id + " " +  li.text);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: thank u very much but the last thing i want to get il id like                       foreach(var li in ul)
    {string id=li.id; 
        Console.WriteLine(li);
    } how to code this in var list

Comment: really i wanna to see u and thank u with my self u solved abig problem 4 me thank u very much

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea to parse html with RegEx. May be you should take into consideration DOM parser, for example [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)